# apply font size in string.format in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using string.format to add text on a chart in Asp.net.

Here is my code,

```
ChartArea1.text = string.Format("10 days : 10% \n 20 days : 20%\n Total : {0:C}", chartValue);
```

Now, for the "10 days : 10%" part, I want to apply a different font size and text alignment.

I tried something like this,

```
ChartArea1.text = string.Format("<span style='font-size: 12px;'>10 days : 10% </span>\n 20 days : 20%\n Total : {0:C}", chartValue);
```

But it is displaying span element in the text.

How can I do this?

Comment: NOTE: font sizes usually accept integer values like '8, 9, 10' and non-integers just added a half like `8.5, 9.5, 10.5`.`

Comment: What is your `ChartArea`? Standard `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea` doesn't has `Text` property.

Comment: It's System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.

Comment: @nrvbha That's a namespace, not a type.

Comment: @nrvbha According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that `ChartArea` doesn't has `Text` property. Are you sure you're using it and not some third-party component?

Comment: Your text is getting html encoded - if you want to avoid that, post your real code, as your pseudo code is wrong.

Comment: ChartArea1 is a title of ChartAreaMain. ChartArea1 = ChartAreaMain.Titles[0];